# Knockout subscribe multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

In a purchase order, I want to calculate total amount of all line items based on prices and taxes. For each item, there are multiple taxes. I am using knockout bindings for this. Everything works except the taxes section. When I add a new tax or remove, its not updating the total. I tried with custom bindings (update), that seems not working for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/krishnasarma/r0doakyk/

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody data-bind='foreach: Entries'>
<tr>
  <td>
  <input type="text" data-bind="value:Amount" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <select multiple data-bind="ddl1: null, SelectedOptions:Taxes"/>
  </td>
</tr>                          
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="text" data-bind="value:$root.Total()" />
```

JS:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.ddl1 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).append('<option value=1>My tax 1</option>');
    $(element).append('<option value=2>My tax 2</option>');
    },
   update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
   alert(valueAccessor());
     }
}


function Entry(child) {
    var self = this;
    self.Amount = ko.observableArray(child.Amount);
    self.Taxes = ko.observableArray(child.Taxes);
}
var VM = {
    Entries: ko.observableArray([]),
    Total: function(){
        var tot = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < VM.Entries().length; i++) {
                var amt =  parseFloat(VM.Entries()[i].Amount());
            var taxtot = 0;
            for(var j=0;j<VM.Entries()[i].Taxes.length;j++){
                    taxtot += amt*parseFloat(VM.Entries()[i].Taxes[j]);
            }
            tot +=taxtot;
        }
        return tot.toFixed(2);

    }
}
$(function () {
        VM.Entries().push(new Entry({}));
    VM.Entries().push(new Entry({}));
        ko.applyBindings(VM);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues in the code:

You do not need custom bindings for the multi-select taxes.  In the HTML, try:

```
<select multiple data-bind="options: $root.TaxOptions, optionsText: function(item) { return item.display; }, selectedOptions: Taxes"/>
```

Then in the JavaScript:

```
self.TaxOptions = [{display: "My Tax 1", value: 1}, {display: "My Tax 2", value: 2}];
```

(See jsfiddle link below for full code)

Create Total as a ko.computed observable since it is dependent on the Entries observable array.

```
self.Total = ko.computed(function() {
    var tot = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < self.Entries().length; i++) {
        var amt =  parseFloat(self.Entries()[i].Amount());    
        var taxtot = 0;
        for(var j=0;j<self.Entries()[i].Taxes().length;j++){
                taxtot += amt*parseFloat(self.Entries()[i].Taxes()[j].value);
        }
        tot +=taxtot;
    }
    return tot.toFixed(2);

    });
```

Note in the above code, when getting the value of Taxes, use parenthesis () since it's an observable array.

This jsFiddle should get you on the right track:

https://jsfiddle.net/ombk322j/